# Display content alternatively from custom post type in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I added 6 different posts on one single custom post type. Like, under Team, there are 6 different members, I want to display these 6 members in two rows, 3 column in each row. How to accomplish it? I am new to WordPress theme development. Trying to code front-page, any suggestions and resources will be appreciated.
What  I did is like this,

```
<section class="team" id="team">
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="team-heading text-center">
<h2>our team</h2>
<h4>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled</h4></div>

    <?php 
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'team',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'    =>3,
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>
     <?php if($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="col-md-2 single-member col-sm-4">
       <div class="person">
       <img class="img-responsive"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
      <div class="person-detail">
        <div class="arrow-bottom"></div>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
     </div>
     </div>
    <!-- Query to display +1/next content-->
    <div class="col-md-2 single-member col-sm-4">
      <div class="person-detail">
       <div class="arrow-top"></div>
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?> </p>
      </div>
    <div class="person">
      <img class="img-responsive"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a front-end problem than PHP. You could go about it in numerous ways, but the simplest is to simply use Bootstrap correctly. Also, if you mix PHP and HTML the way you do, you're gonna end up with unreadable files.

First, the query:

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

Sort `date`, `DESC` is unnecessary as that is the default. `posts_per_page` should not limit the number of returned items.

And the view:

```
<section class="team" id="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="team-heading text-center">...</div>
    <div class="row">
      <?php if($the_query->have_posts()): $i = 0; while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <?php if ($i % 2 > 0): ?>
            <div class="single-member">...tpl1...</div>
          <?php else: ?>
            <div class="single-member">...tpl2...</div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
      <?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The `col-sm-4` should make it so that you get 3 items in a row.

Comment: I am sorry if i couldn't make your clear about my problem, What i want to accomplish is, with the first template tag-> `the_title()` & `the_content()`, i want member 1st, and member 2nd with the successive `the_title()` & `the_content()` tag. Will be greatful if you suggest any other best option to this problem